# How to test whether row is added into database by unit testing?

Tags: objective-c, ios, unit-testing

I am passing the xml to my addRowToTheDatabase function . In this function i simply parse the xml file and and retrieved elements to the xml file. Now I am testing this application. How can I test whether the row added in the database or not in from unit test case ?

Comment: why don't you just query the database after insertion?

Comment: @DJPlayer:can you please explain in details?

Comment: Are you using Core Data? Sqlite directly? Something else?

Comment: No, I am using sqlite directly

Comment: strictly speaking that's an integration test rather than a unit test. Unit tests shouldn't be coupled to a persistent storage implementation.

Comment: @MaxMacLeod:Then how it can be done ?

Comment: there's no problem doing it. But you wouldn't call it a unit test. More an integration test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// I manipulated one of my queries real quick.. I'm assuming you're already connecting to a DB in SQLite, so much of this is un-needed.  But this is the basic structure of a query.. as long as the DB resides in your application itself.

```
-(void) basicQuery
{
    @try {  
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
        NSString *theDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"databasename.sqlite"]; 
        BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:theDBPath]; 
        if (!success) {
            NSLog(@"Failed to find database file '%@'.", theDBPath);
        } 
        if (!(sqlite3_open([theDBPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)) { 
            NSLog(@"An error opening database, normally handle error here.");  
        }  

        const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE"; // your basic query
        sqlite3_stmt *statement; 
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK){ 
            NSLog(@"Error, failed to prepare statement, normally handle error here."); 
        } 
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) { 
          NSString *value = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]; 
           NSLog(@"value = %@",value);

        } 
        if(sqlite3_finalize(statement) != SQLITE_OK){ 
            NSLog(@"Failed to finalize data statement, normally error handling here."); 
        } 
        if (sqlite3_close(database) != SQLITE_OK) { 
            NSLog(@"Failed to close database, normally error handling here."); 
        } 
    } 
    @catch (NSException *e) { 
        NSLog(@"An exception occurred: %@", [e reason]); 
        return nil; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: is this only one way by checking exception?

Comment: I don't usually do things by try, catch.. but Database connects can be awkward.  Usually the NSLog's will do fine, if not use breakpoints and step through checking values.  If this is your first DB insert and query you might want to run through a tutorial.